# How to prevent Qt from linking

Tags: qt, linker, qmake

I have a bigger project including code in different languages. One part of it is written in C++/QML. The final linkage is performed via DMD. I need qmake to generate only object files without linking. Currently qmake tries to link a library, what fails with undefined reference.

Is there a way to make qmake generate only object files without linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the project type to the `lib` template, and add `CONFIG += staticlib`. The static library is simply a single file archive of all your objects. DMD can then link it to the final executable.